# How to import specific function - Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, import

I made a GoldCalcultor in which I used  [react-flags-select](https://github.com/ekwonye-richard/react-flags-select) drop down box. The application works fine. When I use the whole module(import  ReactFlagsSelect  from "react-flags-select";) and build the code, its size increased to 1.13 MB , which is very big.
I further dig down and use specific country codes like this

import { QA, PK, IN, BD, LK, AF, NP, PH, US, GB, SG } from "react-flags-select";

import { default as ReactFlagsSelect } from "react-flags-select"; // In this case it builds upto max size that is 1.13 MB

import { ReactFlagsSelect } from "react-flags-select"; // not recognize as a valid function and warning appear during build

When I used specific country codes my build size decreased to 358k.

During the build, I get the following message
export 'ReactFlagsSelect' (imported as 'ReactFlagsSelect') was not found in 'react-flags-select' (possible exports: Ad, Ae, Af, Ag, Ai, Al, Am, Ao, Ar, As, At, Au, Aw, Az, Ba, Bb, Bd, Be, Bf, Bg, Bh, Bi, Bj, Bm, Bo, Br, Bs, Bt, Bw, By, Bz, Ca, Cd, Cf, Cg, Ch, Ci, Ck, Cl, Cm, Cn, Co, Cr, Cu, Cv, Cw, Cy, Cz, De, Dj, Dk, Dm, Do, Dz, Ec, Ee, Eg, Er, Es, Et, Fi, Fj, Fk, Fm, Fo, Fr, Ga, Gb, Gd, Ge, Gg, Gh, Gi, Gl, Gm, Gn, Gq, Gr, Gt, Gu, Gw, Hk, Hn, Hr, Ht, Hu, Id, Ie, Il, Im, In, Io, Iq, Ir, Is, It, Je, Jm, Jo, Jp, Ke, Kg, Kh, Ki, Km, Kn, Kp, Kr, Kw, Ky, Kz, La, Lb, Lc, Li, Lk, Lr, Ls, Lt, Lu, Lv, Ly, Ma, Mc, Md, Me, Mg, Mh, Mk, Ml, Mm, Mn, Mo, Mp, Mq, Mr, Ms, Mt, Mu, Mv, Mw, Mx, My, Mz, Na, Ne, Nf, Ng, Ni, Nl, No, Np, Nr, Nu, Nz, Om, Pa, Pe, Pf, Pg, Ph, Pk, Pl, Pn, Pr, Ps, Pt, Pw, Py, Qa, Ro, Rs, Ru, Rw, Sa, Sb, Sc, Sd, Se, Sg, Si, Sk, Sl, Sm, Sn, So, Sr, Ss, St, Sv, Sx, Sy, Sz, Tc, Td, Tg, Th, Tj, Tk, Tm, Tn, To, Tr, Tt, Tv, Tw, Tz, Ua, Ug, Us, Uy, Uz, Ve, Vi, Vn, Vu, Ws, Ye, Za, Zm, Zw, default)

Is there any way that I can only import  ReactFlagsSelect specific function?

Thanks